# Change navigation bar links based on route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Objective:** Display specific links in navigation bar for specific routes based on the currently viewed page.

I would like to do something like this in my application.html.haml

`if companies_page
   %li
     = link_to "Contact Us", contact_path`

If there is a better way to do this I am open to suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Clarification: are you looking to display specific links in the navigation bar for specific routes *based on what page is currently being viewed*?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Ok ... I think this SO answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280230/rails-4-bootstrap-3-how-to-display-a-different-navigation-bar-on-different-pa

Comment: How can i mark this as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: I will go ahead and move it to an actual answer, which you can mark if you wish :) ... actually, when I move it to an answer it's "too trivial" and it moves it back to a comment LOL

Answer (score 0):

You might think about using [Tabulous](https://github.com/techiferous/tabulous) which does pretty much exactly that; it allows you to define a set of possible tabs (which you can render as a navigation bar) and also when they should be visible and when they should be active. From the documentation example, part of a tab definition block might be:

```
visible_when   { in_action('any').of_controller('pictures') }
```

Since that's a block you could easily use more complex logic there, but I imagine that would get very hard to conceptualize very quickly.